# C# scripting - How to output a dynamically created list of strings?

Tags: c#, list, scripting, output

I would like to output a list (C# Scripting), which contains elements of objects' names. Since this list is generating dynamacally, I just get a output in every single line. This is my code:

```
public static List<string> myList= new List<string>();
//...
public static void myMethod (Renderer[] renderers) {
        foreach (var renderer in renderers) {
            if (IsVisible(renderer)) {
                //print (renderer.name + " is visible!");
                myList.Add (renderer.name);
            }
            print (myList);
        }
        myList.Clear ();
        print ("--");
       }
```

The output is like `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]`in every line. 
After a reseach I also tried

```
foreach (var item in myList) {
      print (item);
}
```

This method prints every object in a single line. But I want all names of the objects to be together in one line until there will be "--" printed. 
How can I realize it? Thanks!

**Example:**

output now:

```
object0 
object1
object2
etc.
```

what I want to achive: `object0, object1, object2, etc.`

Comment: what's this print ? Console.Write ? What type of application is this winforms/console/web ?

Comment: Is `print` a function you have written?

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx
Console.Writeline(string.Join(",", myList.ToArray());

Comment: @JuanFerrer `print` comes from `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: @Krishna it's like `Debug.Log()`, I'm developing in MonoDevelop for the game engine Unity3D.

Comment: @Viktoria Oh, ok, it comes frome Unity, not `System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print all the names of visible renderers with the following code using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and LINQ

```
public static void myMethod(Renderer[] renderers)
{
    print(string.Join(",", renderers.Where(IsVisible).Select(r => r.name)));
    print("--");
}
```

This should output:

```
object1,object2,object3
--
```

Comment: A very smart solution, thnak you!

Comment: @Viktoria BTW your error was in calling `print (myList);` inside the `foreach` loop. You should have done it after the loop, when all items were already added, You could either put it after or change that line to `Print(renderer.name);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It recevies the separator and an array of strings as parameters. For example:

```
print(String.Join(", ", myList.ToArray());
```

Comment: This works nearly perfect. But now I get an output like 
`object0` (newline)
`object0, object1` (newline)
`object0, object1, object2` ...

Comment: do not execute the print for each element. You need to execute the print at the end of the loop, once the list is filled

Answer (score 1):

If your output coming as a string then u have to take one string variable and concatenate all items with "--" into the variable.

```
string temp = string.Empty;
foreach(var item in items)
{
   temp += item + "--";
}

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Join`for this.

```
string itemsInOneLine = string.Join(", ", myList);
print(itemsInOneLine);
```

For further information have a look at the [MSDN string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) page.

Comment: I'm using a `List<string> myList`, not an Array

Comment: and Join needs as a second parameter an array.

Comment: `string.Join`supports `List<string` ;) Have a look at the MSDN, there is an overload: `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)` and `List<string>` is an `IEnumerable`